# I can't install nestjs in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I was trying to install nestjs to study but... well, it's better to show what happened

first I tried to discover which version of my npm or node was, that was the result:

```
$ npm - v

output: 6.14.16

$ node -v

output: v14.19.1
```

theoretically I can install nest, right? well, I ran this code:

```
$ npm i -g @nestjs/cli

output: /home/user/.npm-global/bin/nest -> 
/home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @nestjs/cli@8.2.3
updated 1 package in 17.045s
```

I figured that this output seemed weird, even so I tried to discover if nest was installed

```
$ nest -v

output: Command 'nest' not found, did you mean:

  command 'newt' from snap newt (0.0.1)
  command 'net' from deb samba-common-bin (2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)
  command 'next' from deb mailutils-mh (1:3.7-2.1)
  command 'next' from deb mmh (0.4-2)
  command 'next' from deb nmh (1.7.1-6)
  command 'test' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)
  command 'nast' from deb nast (0.2.0-7build1)
  command 'neat' from deb neat (2.2-1build1)
  command 'nes' from deb fceux (2.2.2+dfsg0-1build1)
  command 'nes' from deb mednafen (1.22.2+dfsg-1build1)
  command 'nes' from deb nestopia (1.50-1build1)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

I'm really new in this development 'and this is my first post here!' world but I appreciate your attention in my problem (also I'm not from USA so my English might be with lots of mistakes, sorry!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way to solve your issue:

1. Use npx before every nestjs command:

```
  npx @nestjs/cli g controller pages
```

2. Add an alias inside your .bashrc or .zshrc (depend which one you are using):

   To find your node path, type in your terminal:

```
  which node
```

or

```
  which nodejs
```

Then, when you have your path to node:

```
  alias nest="/your/path/to/node/bin/nest"
```

Then in your terminal you can test

```
  nest --version
```

It should work

Comment: THANKS! IT WORKED! GOD BLESS YOU!

Comment: Nada sir. rember to check answer if it's correct.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed you're currently on a older version of Node Package Manager (npm) and you need to upgrade it before you can install stuff like nest.js... So these are the steps

Step 1. clean cache with this command, then you will get a message " I sure hope you know what you are doing" if you're on the track

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

Step 2. Install Node’s version manager

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

Step 3. install a stable version

```
sudo n stable
```

The stable version is ok, but you can install that latest version as well with `sudo n latest`.But i hope you don't have another challenge eventually