# I am unable to install nestjs in ubuntu 20.4

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nestjs

```
arbaz@khan:~$ npm -v
8.19.2
arbaz@khan:~$ node -v
v16.17.0
```

These are my version of node and npm**

When i run the command npm i -g @nestjs/cli
i get the following error:

```
arbaz@khan:~$ npm i -g @nestjs/cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/arbaz/.npm/_logs/2022-09-24T06_37_19_167Z-debug-0.log
arbaz@khan:~$
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71533051/i-cant-install-nestjs-in-ubuntu-20-04) is not helpful for me.

First time I am asking a question in Stackoverflow. Please suggest any anwser related to my question. Thanks

Comment: i fix my problem after lot of thinking the problem was i did not use

Comment: This seems to be my favorite answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67098642/724039) in the question: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules)

Comment: When seeing "permission denied" to  `/usr/`, you should think of using `sudo`.

Comment: @ArbazKhan: Helpful reading about formatting your question: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)   (for next questions, because I already fixed this one )